# How to force Windows 10 to unlock computer following RDP disconnect

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I have a computer that acts as an information display board.  The end user is unhappy with the current solution that's built around XAMPP & WordPress as they're computer illiterate and can't be bothered to learn a "For Dummies"-level set of instructions, so they're scrapping it in favor of a forever looping Microsoft PowerPoint slide show.

One of the issues that they've griped about is that the current system is too hard to connect into (they have to get on the wifi network then open up a browser and go to http://[computer ip address]/wordpress/wp-admin), so I'm trying to make this thing Army-proof to log into by using the remote desktop tools built into Windows 10.  The upside is that it works, and I can use the Android app on my phone to log into the computer.

The downside, and ultimately the problem I'm trying to solve here, is how do I force the computer to go back to the desktop after my phone disconnects the remote session?  This computer is supposed to be displaying a PowerPoint slideshow in perpetual loop, but the remote connection kicks the computer back to the lock screen requiring me to go unlock it after I disconnect the remote session.  Is there any way to get the computer to unlock itself after the remote session disconnects?